# How does alias_method not create infinite loop?

Tags: ruby

I'm confused by [`alias_method`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method). The following example seems it should produce an infinite loop, but it doesn't:

```
  class ApplicationController
    dual_accessor :filter_by, :default => []
  end

  class Class
   def dual_accessor(*attributes)
    options = attributes.extract_options!
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      class_eval <<-ruby
        class_inheritable_accessor :#{attribute}

        singleton_class.send :alias_method, :read_#{attribute}, :#{attribute}

        def self.#{attribute}(value = :__read__)
          if value == :__read__
            read_#{attribute}
          else
            self.#{attribute} = value
          end
        end
      ruby
      self.send(attribute, options[:default]) if options[:default]
    end
   end 
  end
```

As far as I understand,

- we extract the hash `{ default: [] }` into the `options` local variable.
- Then we iterate over splatted array. In this case, the splat just contains `:filter_by`.
- We use `class_eval` to evaluate the string in the heredoc in the context of class object.
- We call `alias_method` on the singleton object of `self`, (`self` refers to an instance of the class).
- We create a new copy of `filter_by` called `read_filter_by`.
- Then we create a class method named `filter_by`, which accepts a default parameter `:__ read __`.
- Rest is self-explanatory.

When we call `read_#{attribute}`, e.g. `read_filter_by`, how does this not create an infinite loop? It seems like the method will call itself over and over recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_filter_by` calls the accessor method created with `class_inheritable_accessor`.

The important thing is that the `read_filter_by` method points at what `filter_by` was when `alias_method` was called  - subsequent redefinitions of `filter_by` don't affect `read_filter_by`

Comment: Note in recent versions of Rails, class_inheritable_accessor has been replaced by class_attribute.